# Is there a way to get the method how the location was processed?

Tags: geolocation

Experimenting with the W3C Geolocation API.
Is there a way to get the method how the location was processed? I mean GPS, IP, Cell IDs etc. I didn't find any object properties doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'user agent' you can detect what device connected to the service to get the location.

Nokia use
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Series_40_web_apps_-_FAQ#Do_you_provide_an_API_to_query_user.27s_location.3F

"A user agent IP lookup also returns the IP of the data centre of Nokia Browser for Series 40 Proxy through which the network traffic is routed. "

Comment: Thanks Mapperz! Not exactly what I wanted but 1 step further maybe.

Comment: ´Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22´
Ok, I see this is a desktop computer probably without GPS, but how does this info help me to know if the phone user's location is an accurate GPS location or just a Cell ID or WiFi or sth else?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface requires the user agent to determine user-agent specific algorithm & getCurrentPosition()

Comment: But what is this user-agent specific algorithm?